# c# method doesn't change public variable

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I have a problem with a variable in a public method not changing a variable. The method executes everything except the bit that changes the variable.

This is in my main form:

```
namespace Multi_tool
{
    public partial class startForm : Form
    {
        public string quantity;
        public string value;
        public string unit;

        public void startInmForm(string _quantity,string _unit)
        {
            //Here I think something is wrong
            quantity = _quantity;
            unit = _unit;

            inmForm inmForm = new inmForm();
            inmForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Later on I call the method:

```
        private void btnVelocity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startInmForm("Velocity", "m/s");
        }
```

In another form i have this code:

```
namespace Multi_tool
{
    public partial class inmForm : Form
    {
        public inmForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void inmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startForm startForm = new startForm();

            lblQuantity.Text = startForm.quantity;
            lblUnit.Text = startForm.unit;
        }
```

It (`inmForm`) is a form with two labels and a textbox in the middle, and a value should be typed in the textbox. The labels should have the text "Velocity" and "m/s", but they are booth empty. Why is that?

If I assign text to `quantity` or `unit` when I declare it, that text shows up on the label on the second form (`inmForm`).

Very thankfull for help!

Comment: Have you placed a break point in your method to see if it actually runs? And just FYI, placing a `_` before the variable name is usually used to signify a global variable in c#. Seems like you may have mixed it up with a parameter name.

Comment: @Tdorno Yes, the method runs because the inmForm opens. My only problem is that the method will not pass the new values. Ps. I'm quite new to c# so I don't now all the small rules yet, but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `new startForm()` you create a new instance and not use the existing one.
You need to send parameters from startForm to inmForm before call ShowDialog. (Property or constuctor)

```
public partial class inmForm : Form
{
    private startForm _startForm;
    public inmForm(startForm startForm)
    {
        _startForm = startForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void inmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblQuantity.Text = _startForm.quantity;
        lblUnit.Text = _startForm.unit;
    }
}
```

in startInmForm

```
public void startInmForm(string _quantity,string _unit)
{
    //Here I think something is wrong
    quantity = _quantity;
    unit = _unit;

    inmForm inmForm = new inmForm(this);
    inmForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
    private void inmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startForm startForm = new startForm();

        lblQuantity.Text = startForm.quantity;
        lblUnit.Text = startForm.unit;
    }
```

You are instantiating a form and immediately set the values to a textbox, the values are still null at this time.

Try this for instance:

```
    private void inmForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startForm startForm = new startForm();
        startForm.startInmForm("Velocity", "m/s");
        lblQuantity.Text = startForm.quantity;
        lblUnit.Text = startForm.unit;
    }
```

As a sidenote. Try to name your classes with a capital. This makes it easier to differentiate between classes and variables.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But adding the line you suggest gives a 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' with additional information "Unable to make windowreference" at 'inmForm.ShowDialog();' in 'startInmForm'.